# XSL: Adding an extra digit to the coordinate data

Tags: xml, xslt

I receive coordinate data in an XML file in the form of 
Latitude: 3876570
Longitude:-9013376

I am using XSL to convert the Lon/lat to have 8 digits instead of 7 (as above), so I need to append a zero at the end of the above coordinates. ie I need
Latitude: 38765700
Longitude:-90133760

I am trying to use format-number() function, but not sure if I am using it correctly. I tried

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(longitude, "########")'/>
```

and

```
 <xsl:value-of select='format-number(longitude, "#######0")'/>
```

I end up getting the 7 digits itself. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `format-number` can't give you the result you want as it cannot change the value of the number it represents.

You can either multiply the value by ten (there's no need for a `format-number` call as long as you're using XSLT 1.0)

```
<xsl:value-of select="longitude * 10" />
```

or append a zero

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(longitude, '0')" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The obvious answer -- multiplying by 10 or concatenating with a `'0'` was already proposed.

**Here is a more generic solution**:

This transformation adds the exact number of necessary zeroes at the end of `latitude` and `longitude` for any value with `string-length()` less than 8:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="
 *[self::latitude or self::longitude
 and
   not(string-length() >= 8)
 or
  (starts-with(., '-') and not(string-length() >= 9))
  ]">

  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(.,
            substring('00000000',
                      1,
                      8 + starts-with(., '-') - string-length())
           )
    "/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<coordinates>
 <latitude>3876570</latitude>
 <longitude>-9013376</longitude>
</coordinates>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<coordinates>
   <latitude>38765700</latitude>
   <longitude>-90133760</longitude>
</coordinates>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<coordinates>
 <latitude>123</latitude>
 <longitude>-99</longitude>
</coordinates>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<coordinates>
   <latitude>12300000</latitude>
   <longitude>-99000000</longitude>
</coordinates>
```

**Do note**:

In the expression:

```
substring('00000000',
          1,
          8 + starts-with(., '-') - string-length())
```

we use the fact that whenever a boolean value is an argument to an arithmetic operator, it is converted to a number using the rule that:

```
   number(true()) = 1
```

and

```
   number(false()) = 0
```

So, the above expression extracts one more zero in case the value of the current node is negative -- to account of the minus sign and get the exact number of zeroes that we must append to the number.